# Mocking a command and getting different results based on the number of times the Mock is called

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, pester

I'm using Pester to unit test some code I've written. In the tests I mock `Test-Path` using a parameter filter:

```
Mock -CommandName 'Test-Path' -MockWith { return $false } `
    -ParameterFilter { $LiteralPath -and $LiteralPath -eq 'c:\dummy.txt' }
```

The following is psuedo code for what I'm doing:

```
If ( Test-Path -LiteralPath c:\dummy.txt )
{
    return "Exists"
}
else
{
    Attempt to get file

    If ( Test-Path -LiteralPath c:\dummy.txt )
    {
        return "File obtained"
    }   
}
```

On the first call to `Test-Path` I want to return `$false` and on the second call I want to return `$true`. I can think of a couple of ways of achieving this, but they don't feel right:

1. On the first call use the `Path` parameter and on the second use `LiteralPath`. Have two mocks one with a `ParameterFilter` for each. I don't like the idea of hacking the code in order to facilitate a test.
2. Create a function with parameters for: `Path` and `InstanceNumber`. Create mocks for the function. This is better than the above, but I don't like the idea of having a parameter just for testing purposes.

I've looked and can't find a way to mock based on the nth call. Does Pester facilitate this and I've just missed it? If not is there a cleaner way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Changing the result of a mockup depending on how often it's been called seems ... wrong. What is your test case supposed to validate in the first place?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm testing all paths through my code. So I need to hit both return statements. My intention is to have two "It" blocks one for each return statement. To get to the second return statement Test-Path must return $false to the first test and $true to the second test.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps you can have the mockup return the value of a global variable and change the value of that variable to `$false` in an `AfterEach` block (or the mockup itself). Personally I'd probably define separate contexts with separate mockups for each case, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Not sure that your suggestions would work. Bare in mind that each test will hit both Test-Path statements, and I need a different result for each one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function Test-File{
    If ( Test-Path -LiteralPath c:\dummy.txt )
            {
                return "Exists"
            }
            else
            {
                If ( Test-Path -LiteralPath c:\dummy.txt )
                {
                    return "File obtained"
                }   
            }
}


Describe "testing files" {
    it "file existence test" {
        #Arrange
        $script:mockCalled = 0
        $mockTestPath = {
                            $script:mockCalled++                                
                            if($script:mockCalled -eq 1)
                            {
                                return $false
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return $true
                            }
                        }

            Mock -CommandName Test-Path -MockWith $mockTestPath 
            #Act
            $callResult = Test-File 

            #Assert
            $script:mockCalled | Should Be 2
            $callResult | Should Be "File obtained"
            Assert-MockCalled Test-Path -Times $script:mockCalled -ParameterFilter { $LiteralPath -and $LiteralPath -eq 'c:\dummy.txt' }


        }
}
```

I think you are after this?! let me know if not!

Comment: Thanks, a simple but effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably lies in how you are writing your functions is making the testing unwieldy as the functions are probably becoming the same...

Instead you should abstract functionality out of your main function which allows you to test them individually. I don't know your code but this is just my 2 cents...

```
function MyFunction {
    param (
        $Path
    )

    $exists = (TestPathFirstCall $Path) -eq $true

    if (-not $exists) {
        $exists = (TryToCreateTheFile $Path) -eq $true
    }

    return $exists
}

function TestPathFirstCall {
    param (
        [string] $Path
    )
    Test-Path $Path
}

function TryToCreateTheFile {
    param (
        [string] $Path
    )
    New-Item $Path
    Test-Path $Path
}


Describe 'Test-Path Tests' {
    It 'Tries Test-Path twice, fails first time and returns true' {
        Mock TestPathFirstCall {
            return $false
        }

        Mock TryToCreateTheFile {
            return $true
        }

        MyFunction "C:\dummy.txt" | Should BeExactly $true
        Assert-MockCalled -Exactly TestPathFirstCall -Scope It -Times 1
        Assert-MockCalled -Exactly TryToCreateTheFile -Scope It -Times 1
    }

    It 'Tries Test-Path once and succeeds' {
        Mock TestPathFirstCall {
            return $true
        }

        Mock TryToCreateTheFile {
            return $true
        }

        MyFunction "C:\dummy.txt" | Should BeExactly $true
        Assert-MockCalled -Exactly TestPathFirstCall -Scope It -Times 1
        Assert-MockCalled -Exactly TryToCreateTheFile -Scope It -Times 0
    }

    It 'Tries Test-Path twice and fails' {
        Mock TestPathFirstCall {
            return $false
        }

        Mock TryToCreateTheFile {
            return $false
        }

        MyFunction "C:\dummy.txt" | Should BeExactly $false
        Assert-MockCalled -Exactly TestPathFirstCall -Scope It -Times 1
        Assert-MockCalled -Exactly TryToCreateTheFile -Scope It -Times 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example function only calls `Test-Path` once and so your simple mocks work fine.

I'm not sure you are understanding my requirements, and by the way, the suggested solution works. It's not uncommon for a command to be used multiple times within a single function. `Test-Path` in my example. If the first `Test-Path` fails, then I get the file and check that this was successful. So first `Test-Path` = $false and second `Test-Path` = $true. So, when mocking I need to have a different result for each.

Comment: Simple change to make.

Comment: Unfortuanately, the `Mock` of `Test-Path` always returns `$true`. Also, both tests fail because an array is being returned `@($true, $true)`. The first `$true` is the one in the body of the `if` statement. The second one is the result of the second `Test-Path`. If I comment out the `$true` in the body of the `if` statement the tests pass. But this is a red herring based on the `Mock` not working.

Comment: Also, the `Assert-MockCalled` are misleading. If you change `Times` for `Exactly` The second test fails. This is because `Test-Path` is called twice by both tests.

Comment: I don't like the abuse of the `Path` parameter. It's expected to be a string array, not a `PSCustomObject`. This is messing with the code to make the test work. The test should test the code you've written.

Comment: The problem lies in how you're writing your functions then. They're not easily testable. You should abstract the calls to Test-Path into private functions in a separate psm1. I've updated to show a working example with all your gripes gone.

Comment: I mean how many times are you really going to be calling Test-Path consecutively in the same function before that function becomes unwieldy and you should split up the calls to test path into somewhere else.

Comment: I think your observation about refactoring the example is valid and another way to achieve the desired result. However, over the years I have come across a number of occasions when a command is used more than once in a function with different desired results. So that the ability to mock based on the nth call to the command with different results is still needed.

Comment: That's true and sometimes refactoring can be too difficult due to poor previous design decisions. At least it gives you some other ideas and it also gave me some too... Good discussion.